# What does SourceSet.compiledBy actually do?

Tags: gradle

When you have a block like this:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'spec/src'
      srcDir 'shared/src'
      srcDir 'server/src'
    }
    resources {
      srcDir 'spec/src'
      srcDir 'shared/src'
      srcDir 'server/src'
    }
    compiledBy 'wsGen'
  }
}
```

What does `compiledBy` accomplish? Is it just for caching/performance? Does it cause the task to be run as part of the `compileJava` tasks? The API docs say that it

> Registers a set of tasks which are responsible for compiling this source set into the classes directory. The paths are evaluated as per `Task.dependsOn(java.lang.Object[])`.

That's great, but I have a Gradle project that seems to be running the `wsGen` task when it's not in the `dependsOn` list for anything. Is `compiledBy` where this is coming from?

I'm less trying to solve a problem with this question than I am just trying to understand the mechanics of this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is where it comes from, but no, this is not directly related to the `compileJava` task. Effectively the `compiledBy` option sets the `builtBy` option of the `ConfigurableFileCollection` that represents the output of the source set. The `classes` task that is added by the `JavaBasePlugin` depends on the `compileJava` task, the `processResources` task and said `ConfigurableFileCollection` which in turn causes the task to be executed as it is an implicit transitive dependency of the `classes` task.

Comment: Okay. So to make sure I understand: `compiledBy` is a general configuration item that may affect the task hierarchy that's generated by other plugins such as the Java plugin, causing the specified `compiledBy` task to be run as an indirect dependency of `compileJava`?

Comment: No, as I said already, it is in no way at all affiliated in any way to the `compileJava` task. In Gradle you can tell `ConfigurableFileCollections` (a collection of files as the name suggests) which Gradle tasks create the files that make up the content of the file collection. If the file collection is used somewhere, the task that needs to be run to create the contained files is automatically executed. The `classes` task depends on this file collection that is the output of the source set and thus the task is executed if you execute the `classes` task.